# Double sided board w/ d2paks, solder paste?

Tags: pcb-fabrication, solder-paste

Can you use paste on a double-sided board w/ d2paks on both sides? There is a small area below the tab but it seems like not really enough room for paste.  If not, then how the heck do you do a double sided dpaks?

Comment: If soldering by hand, see related question/answer: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/6552/2028

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your assembly vendor. One thing they might be able to do is glue down the parts on one side of the board so they don't fall off during reflow on the other side. But they might have specific recommendations about how/where to place heavy parts like D-Paks for the best yield.

Comment: yeah im thinking dpaks should be just single side..